# Ignoring included file's exit or die

Tags: php

I'm looking for a method to ignoring die() or exit functions.

Here is an example

Main file:

```
//Here some process
include 'seconfdile.php';
```

Second file:

```
 //Some process
 die();
 //more process
```

Comment: You can comment them out.

Comment: Heheh .. eval(str_replace("die();",'',file_get_contents("seconfdile.php")));

Comment: Add more code explaining the context of your question.

Comment: Ignoring `die` is not an appropriate solution. You should either remove or replace the `die` or change your logic.

Comment: Sorry for short description, Code has ioncubed so i cannot modify. in some case dies and first file dies also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `die()` use `return` in second file.
The die() in include/child file will kill the parent script execution as well.
So, its better to use return instead of die() it will terminate only child/include file not the parent file